# How can I combine three spheres properly?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to combine three spheres in a way that I can be able to modify the crease, like making the crease sharper or more round. I've tried using boolean but it doesn't come out quite right when I use subdivision modifier or when I use smooth shade.
[image: three spheres]

[image: three spheres using boolean and smooth shade]

Answer (score 12):

You might consider using metaballs for this.

You'll get a clean-ish quad based topology but may have limited control over bevel radius for the unions.

[image]

Go to *Add > Metaball > Ball*. In the *Properties Window > Object Data* tab, increase the detail by lowering the *Resolution Viewport* to a lower value like $0.05$, adjust *Resolution Render* accordingly.

Enter *Edit Mode* and from the *Properties Toolshelf*, under *Item > Transform* increase the *Stiffness* value to $10$ or above. Values higher than $10$ can apparently only be achieved by scaling in the viewport with <kbd>S</kbd>, typing in higher numbers doesn't seem to work.

Exit *Edit Mode* and duplicate the spheres using <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>D</kbd> and place them at will.

Meta objects will naturally ensure a rounded bevel over the joints, and will also update live as you move them around. Topology will not naturally follow object shape though, like manual modelling would.

Comment: By "Metal" do you mean shading?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady meta* :p

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady I meant internet slang for brutal and edgy like the music genre. :D Just kidding, silly typo, Thanks for the correction, Allen

Answer (score 8):

To get a clean Boolean, topology must line up exactly.

If you're doing that with UV spheres, figuring out how many rings, segments, tweaking scale and distance to get topology to match, can be a real pain. Geometry Nodes begins to bring parametric modelling to Blender, so it might be worth hacking together a tool like this..

[image]

.. which makes it much easier to adjust everything, while working under  further *Bevel* and *Subdivision* Modifiers. If you set the *Bevel* 'Inner Miter' to 'Arc', you can get control over the central intersection by adjusting its spread.

[image]

The tool could be generalized.. supposing you were doing molecular modelling, or something, you could set the instancing framework as a parameter.. or the modifier could be kept in the bottom drawer and re-hacked for other one-off jobs.

[image]

Comment: That's an impressive approach I would not have thought of.  The result looks really nice.  Complicated to set up, yes, but really clean topology with a very low polygon count!

Comment: Thanks, @Ben !   I've often built temporary jigs for accuracy, as snapping targets, etc., for geometric modelling, but now you can often build a re-usable modifier in about the same time. :)

Comment: I was thinking about geonodes, but didn't occur to me to make the axes parallel - seems obvious once you see the answer. Also, is boolean even needed? Isn't it topologically a cylinder with adjusted vertex positions?

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady, that's an interesting thought.. you mean, just deform some other sphere-equivalent? You could get rid of the poles.

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  [Best I can do, so far](https://imgur.com/a/hIiTZzz)..  preparation of geometry, followed by normalization about  3 points.

Comment: @RobinBetts looks pretty sweet! I was thinking about reproducing exactly the topology in your answer, but starting with a cylinder - you would need to reason about finding the poles on the top/bottom of the cylinder, and go from there with what vertices to merge... But I think it's definitely doable... I don't think I'll find time for it myself, though, Quellenform attacks me about improving the sorting algorithm...

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady  [This one does start with a cylinder](https://pasteall.org/blend/69d8f0862c1c4bcbbac8385959f3c9dd) ... agreed... the problem is rather niche :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Oh yeah, I meant the answer as opposed to the comment.

Answer (score 7):

You could try with an UV sphere or with a cube that you subdivide:

[image]

Then boolean and only keep 1/4th of the result, rework the topology a bit:

[image]

Give it a *Mirror* and a Subdivision Surface:

[image]

If you want the seam to be sharper you'll just need to add edge loops:

[image]