# Bevel intersections between Geometry Nodes instances

Tags: geometry-nodes, workflow, bevel

How can I bevel or somehow mold between instances in geonodes?

Thanks

[image]

[image]

Comment: After boolean perhaps this would work: [How to eliminate obvious proximity crease intersections?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/277581/60486)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265925/how-can-i-combine-three-spheres-properly/