How to make a bubbly shaped smoke mesh quickly?
What's the best approach for this kind of mesh? I know I can just bunch spheres together and boolean them but I'm wondering if there's a better way with geo nodes or something. I've googled this and only thing that came up is using voronoi as displacement but it's not close to the look I want. Someone in blender discord also suggested metaballs but I can't achieve the same corner shape with it. I'm looking to use this mesh in UE5 niagara for an explosion fx.




Are you intending to animate it like your second image above?? I might have a look at simulation nodes or particle nodes, using simple spheres as the instance. You can get some nice stylized smoke plumes that way.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/194011/is-there-any-technique-to-give-a-metaball-effect-to-the-particles-emitting-from/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265925/how-can-i-combine-three-spheres-properly/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/244655/whats-the-most-fun-way-to-make-a-snowman-in-blender-%ef%b8%8e%ef%b8%8e%ef%b8%8e/244710#244710

Metaballs was indeed the answer and I'm just a big bakasussy.


